# `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `development' for AppName::Application:Class (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railtie

Rail version - 4.2.3 
When i try to start my app in production environment

```
rails s RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get this error :

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:196:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`development'

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

or

```
rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurred because of specifying wrong configuration in application.rb file